# pass values from one PHP page to another with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have tied for hours now to get the values  value="oneyearanalysis" and value="oneyearanalysis", of each button when i press them, i tried with ajax. I think i am close but i get no output GetData but i do in my console.log(clikYear);. Hope you can help me

Best regards

**Index.php**

```
  <div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">
      <select  name="button" id="button">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        <option value="oneyearanalysis">1 year analyse</option>
      <option value="fiveyearanalysis">5 year analyse</option>
  </select>
    </div>


$(document).ready(function(){ 
      $("#button").on("change",function() {
            var clikYear = $(this).val();
                  console.log(clikYear);
                  if (clikYear !== "") {
                    var getTableCall2 = $.ajax({
                      url : "GetData.php",
                      type:"POST",
                      cache:false,
                      data:{clikYear:clikYear},              
                    })
                  }
            });
            getTableCall2.done(function(data){
              console.log(data);
              console.log(getTableCall2);
              console.log(clikYear);
          })
```

**GetData.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['clikYear']))
{
    $year= $_POST['clikYear'];
}
$yearOfChoice = $year;
```

Comment: Your php script doesn’t output anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were quite close to make it work. If you apply the simple recommandations below, you should save yourself that kind of trouble in the future.

1. **First recommandation** is to indent your code correctly.
   You would have noticed the `getTableCall2` variable is declared on `select` `change`. But "used" before that when trying to apply the `.done()` promise handler.

   Below, I made no change to you code except the indentation.
   The order of execution on document ready is:

- Register the `change` handler (not executed)
- Throw an error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").on("change",function() {
    var clikYear = $(this).val();
    console.log(clikYear);
    if (clikYear !== "") {
      var getTableCall2 = $.ajax({
        url : "GetData.php",
        type:"POST",
        cache:false,
        data:{clikYear:clikYear},
      })
    }
  });
  getTableCall2.done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    console.log(getTableCall2);
    console.log(clikYear);
  })
```

2. **Second recommandation** is to use the [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) where you would have seen this error:

> ReferenceError: getTableCall2 is not defined.

3. **Third recommandation** is to be a bit more creative with you `class` and `id` naming.
    `.button` used on a `<select>` just can lead to confusion. You can use the name you want. Make it meaningful! I'm sure you do not use the word `door` when you talk about a `window` in the real life...

So here is something that should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#analysis_term").on("change",function() {
    var clikYear = $(this).val();
    console.log(clikYear);

    if (clikYear !== "") {
      var getTableCall2 = $.ajax({
        url : "GetData.php",
        type:"POST",
        cache:false,
        data:{clikYear:clikYear},
      })
      
      getTableCall2.done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
      })
    }
  });
});
```

And to test it, make sure the `GetData.php` outputs something in both cases:

```
$year = "No POST value!";

if(isset($_POST['clikYear'])){
  $year= $_POST['clikYear'];
}

echo "The POST value is:" . $year;
```

Answer (score 1):

The ID for your Select is "button" but you are using Class Selector instead. Try replacing . with # in front of button

HTML

```
<select id="button">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="oneyearanalysis">1 year analyse</option>
    <option value="fiveyearanalysis">5 year analyse</option>
</select>
```

JQuery

```
$("#button").on("change", function () {
    var clikYear = $(this).val();
    console.log(clikYear);
    if (clikYear !== "") {
        $.ajax({
            url: "GetData.php",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: { clikYear: clikYear },
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I get the value out in index.php, but i can't seem to pass it on tho the other page. Can you help me why?

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP, I tried with .NET and it works. Can you put a breakpoint on the method that is being called from ajax and see if it hits it? please look at the my code i have updated it